# Problem installing the rstudio on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio, ubuntu-20.04, libssl

I'm trying to install the rstudio on ubuntu 20.04 but it is saying the the libssl1.0.0,libssl1.0.2, and the libssl1.1 is not installed. Someone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the latest version of RStudio, that was released yesterday, but it did not work.

So, I am using daily build one. You can download it from https://dailies.rstudio.com/

I hope this can help some.

Comment: More specific answer with explanation will help better.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, though it might help someone.

O/S:      `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`

R:     `R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330) -- "Innocent and Trusting" Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`

RStudio:  `2022.12.0 Build 353` or `"Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for Ubuntu Jammy` or `RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Ubuntu Jammy Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36`

So the install process

1. update system `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.  Ths may take some time.
2. install dependencies `apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common`
3. install broken dependencies `sudo apt --fix-broken install`  This fixed the `libssl` and `libclang` errors that I was getting.
4. install R, go to `https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/` and follow the script there.  To run R,  `sudo -i R`  To exit back to the terminal `quit()`
5. download RStudio `wget -c https://download1.rstudio.org/electron/jammy/amd64/rstudio-2022.12.0-353-amd64.deb'`

Note:  RStudio download page has moved to Posit,  `https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/`  R/Click the link for the source `https://download1.rstudio.org/electron/jammy/amd64/rstudio-2022.12.0-353-amd64.deb`.  Also another place to find the .deb builds are on `https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/` (nice flower images RStudio)

6. `cd` to your download folder and in the terminal run `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-2022.12.0-353-amd64.deb` or what ever version that you have downloaded.  You may have to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` at this time once more.
7. to run RStudio from the terminal, simply type `rstudio` or to get access to the terminal at the same time `rstudio &` and press `Return` in the terminal.

Any feedback would be appreciated.